Black comedy mini-series with bloody shootings in public toilet

Black comedy mini-series (several episodes) about mafia/gansters.
I've watched it in the 90's.
Most probably in colour.
I don't remember the language spoken, but my guess would be that the show was French or British.
Based on how the characters were dressed it was set sometime between the 20's and the 60's.
I remember only very graphic scenes where some characters were shot while in a stall in a public toilet. The killer was shooting from outside the stall and the victim's blood was squirting through bullet holes in the door.
There were several such scenes and each time one character was shot. The comical element was that due to mistakes each time the killer was shooting at incorrect person. I think it was something like this: A wanted to kill B, but by mistake killed C. That lead to D trying to revenge C, but instead killing B, etc. I remember finding this plot very funny.

